# Freeze on updating multiple Gtk.Widget

Tags: gtk, drawing, refresh, pygtk

**I have to update 3 Gtk.Label and several Gtk.DrawingArea** every 1 second/0.1 second/0.5 second etc. , but i don't know why ***the software freezes after about 10 seconds***.

I tried *gtk.gdk.threads_enter/leave* or using a *lock*, but anyway **the update doesn't happen at the same time, but instead it is sequential.** (so there isn't any Gtk.Widget shared with several callbacks)

Let's have a look at the code:

```
#updating Gtk.DrawingArea
for ip in self.__cpu_info.keys(): 
    self.__cpu_info[ip]['drawing_area'].show()
    self.__cpu_info[ip]['drawing_area'].queue_draw()

#updating Gtk.Label
self.__Media_aritmetica_Label.set_text('%.2f' % self.__cpu_medie['media_aritmetica'])
self.__Media_mobile_Label.set_text('%.2f' % self.__cpu_medie['media_mobile'])
self.__Mediana_Label.set_text('%.2f' % self.__cpu_medie['mediana'])
```

**NOTE ::** the software freezes with just one of the 2 pieces above (so with both of them it takes less time to freeze)

Comment: Please, show some _real_ code, the above is just too short.

Comment: Ok let's begin with drawing and updating several Gtk.DrawingArea. Please, run the files at: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ly18mj6tg4e22jc/AACEuvzO4IneAtYG_-v-k-Wua/drawing

Comment: Place your code inline to your question (code tags are your friends).

Comment: Also there are numerous other errors I get due to missing imports. Fix that mess first. Also naming variables in Italian and commenting in Italian is not helpful at all.

Comment: the 2 comments included are just useless (as the example is so easy to understand). Speaking about the errors, i just got many **Pango-CRITICAL error** and **Gtk-CRITICAL error**; this is due to the update of the several Gtk.Label, and it will cause the termination of the software

Comment: All I want is a minimal reproducable example *that actually works*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `GObject.idle_add` (`GObject.timeout_add` would allow you to get rid of the second thread completely) with a function that modifies/accesses the `GtkWidget`. All access to drawing related functions have to be called from one (1) thread! `idle/timeoout_add` do serialize the callback into the glib mainloop, which is what you want.

Comment: Thanks, but.. oh my gosh, now i have to work on this problem (so at this time it stops after a pair of seconds: error code 139)
`Couldn't register with accessibility bus: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
`

Comment: Open up a new question, if I get the time, I'll have a look.